# Possible file actions from programs in Java?

Tags: java, file

I am currently working on a file browser in java. The native Windows Explorer displays further options in the context menu if you have installed programs like Kaspersky. You can scan a file for viruses using the context menu. Now I want to have the same option in my program.

How do I get possible file options from other programs? Is there a way to make this platform independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that there is a platform independent solution for your problem as the context menu depends on desktop environments (Gnome, KDE, Xfce, Windows) and everywhere it's implemented differently (registry files, [nautilus scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-do-i-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus), etc).

In Windows, you can find the context menu items [in registry](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors):

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
```

how to read registry is described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java).